# Ansible 2.6: Is there a way to reference the playbook's name in a role task?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Given a playbook like this:

```
- name: "Tasks for service XYZ"
  hosts: apiservers
  roles:
    - { role: common }
```

Is there a way to reference the playbook's name ("Tasks for service XYZ")? (i.e. a variable)

---

EDIT:

My intention is to be able to reference the playbook's name in a role task, i.e. sending a msg via slack like

```
- name: "Send Slack notification indicating deploy has started"
  slack:
    channel: '#project-deploy'
    token: '{{ slack_token }}'
    msg: '*Deploy started* to _{{ inventory_hostname }}_ of `{{ PLAYBOOK_NAME }}` version *{{ service_version }}*'
  delegate_to: localhost
  tags: deploy
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your intention. Do you want something like `- name: "{{task_name}}"` if yes simply define a variable `task_name: "Tasks for service XYZ"`

Comment: Thanks for the correction @JGK.

Comment: @JGK My intention is actually to be able to get the name of the playbook in a role so I can use the name in the role (i.e. sending a msg to slack with the inventory's name)

Comment: Just to be precise, what your are referencing here is not the playbook name but the **play** name. You have a response below by @alexb involving ansible 2.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was added in [2.8](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/special_variables.html):

> **ansible_play_name**
>   The name of the currently executed play. Added in `2.8`.

Comment: this is not playbook file name, it is a name defined in playbook

Answer (score 4):

No, the special variables for Ansible are documented [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/special_variables.html), and you can see that there is no variable to return the playbook name.

As mentioned in the comments, however, you can always do this:

```
---
- name: "{{ task_name }}"
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    task_name: "Tasks for service XYZ"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ task_name }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll go that way. Is weird ansible has {{ role_name }} and not {{ playbook_name }}

Answer (score 2):

From your circumstances, it looks like you only want this for audit/notification purposes? In that case  (and assuming unixy clients), using

```
lookup('file', '/proc/self/cmdline') | regex_replace('\u0000',' ')
```

will give you the entire command line that `ansible-playbook` was called with, parameters and all, which would include the playbook name. Depending on your circumstances, that might be a useful enough tradeoff.

Comment: "unixy" does not necessarily involve the existence of a `/proc` file system; only "linuxy" does